# Manually add an entry to the list of tracked entries

Tags: biblatex, etoolbox, comma-separated-list

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I can't manage to write a macro to manually add an `entrykey` to the list of tracked entries in `biblatex` such that `\ifciteseen` will be true.

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose,citetracker=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\makeatletter
\def\sbl@blx@trackentry@global#1{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\xifinlistcs{#1}{blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}
       {}
       {\listcsxadd{blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}{#1}}}
    {}}
\let\trackentry\sbl@blx@trackentry@global
\def\showtrackedentries{\csshow{blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\trackentry{augustine}

\showtrackedentries

\cite{augustine}

\showtrackedentries

\cite{augustine}

\showtrackedentries
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` detokenizes entry keys, so the test fails unless the argument to `\trackentry` is run through `\blx@xsanitizeafter`. This works:

```
\def\sbl@blx@trackentry@global#1{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\blx@xsanitizeafter{\def\sbl@blx@tempa}{#1}%
     \xifinlistcs{\sbl@blx@tempa}{blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}
       {}
       {\listcsxadd{blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}{\sbl@blx@tempa}}}
    {}}
```